# Installing python module gambit on Windows: problem with MinGW and autotools

Tags: mingw, autotools, gambit

I'm trying to install the Python module "Gambit" on Windows.
From the [documentation](https://gambitproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html), it seems like I need to

- download Gambit
- install MinGW
- get the correct packages, so that the autotool commands work
- build Gambit from source
- then build the Python extension

I already installed MinGW ([this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) version), added C:\MinGW\bin to my environment variables and used its package manager to install mingw32-autoconf, mingw32-automake, mingw32-libtool. Didn't find aclocal and libtoolize (thought libtool might work instead) in the package manager.

In my folder C:\MinGW\bin, there are files (without extension) for all of this though (aclocal, libtoolize, ...).

In the folder C:\MinGW\var\cache\mingw-get\packages, there are files which correspond to the packages I have installed. These are either .tar.lzma or .tar.xz files.
I suppose I need to unpack them somehow(?)

If I use the command line (cmd.exe) all of the commands for the autotools don't work (doesn't matter if I write "automake" or "mingw32-automake", I tried both).
"mingw-get" command works and opens the package manager, so doesn't seem to be a problem with the environment variables.

Any help would be appreciated!

Remark: I realize this is moreso a MinGW/autotools question than a Python/gambit one but I added the context, so if there is a shortcut around this annoying installation process people can tell me.

Comment: No, you do not unpack the archives.  This has already been done for you by the package manager.

Comment: The docs say that there are pre-built packages available for Windows.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: The pre-built package for Windows (as far as I've understood), is for the Gambit application, but not for the python package, unless you found something different than I did.
Under "Building the Python package", the documentation is very short and I'm not sure if the Gambit application I downloaded suffices or if I need to build from source

Comment: It is unlikely, albeit not impossible, that you would need to build the Gambit application from source to be able to install / use the Python package.  It is possible, albeit not certain, that the binary package in fact contains a prebuilt (to the extent that building is needed at all) Python package.  If the docs don't tell you then look at the actual installation and maybe try setting up the Python package without building the application.  Because lucking out even just a little on this will make things a lot easier for you.